# how to post complex array to mvc c# api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, api

I'm trying to post an array tat one of it's members (th) is an array of strings, I stringify the array, here is hob it looks stringified:

```
[{"id":"201669887","name":"אורה","Sunday":"1","Monday":"1","Tuesday":"1","Wednesday":"0","Thursday":"1","Friday":"1","Sunday1":"1","Monday1":"1","Tuesday1":"1","Wednesday1":"0","Thursday1":"1","Friday1":"0","totalWorkHour":9,"th":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"year":" ","schoolName":null,"schoolNumber":null},{"id":"201669887","name":"חנה","Sunday":"1","Monday":"1","Tuesday":"1","Wednesday":"0","Thursday":"1","Friday":"1","Sunday1":"1","Monday1":"1","Tuesday1":"1","Wednesday1":"0","Thursday1":"1","Friday1":"0","totalWorkHour":9,"th":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
```

I have a model in Mvc:

```
public class teachersExcelDataModel
    {

  .....
    public int Thursday1 { get; set; }
    public int Friday1 { get; set; }
    public int totalWorkHour { get; set; }

     public List<string> th { get; set; }

     public string schoolName { get; set; }
    public int schoolNumber { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }

        public teachersExcelDataModel()
        {
            th = new List<string>();
        }

    }
```

here is how i send it:

```
this.http.post(this.accessPointUrl3, JSON.stringify(this.sendData), { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(
  noteRecord => {
    if (noteRecord)
      this.a = true;
  }
);
```

and here is how I get it:

```
 public void PostExportExcel([FromBody]List<teachersExcelDataModel>json)
```

but it comes null,
if i get it as object[], it;s okay, 
where am i wrong?

Comment: remove `JSON.stringify`

Comment: so the count is 0 instead of null,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your example JSON string is not in correct format.
2. After fixing the format of the json, you will see that **you are trying to parse `schoolNumber` field to integer, which in your case is `null`** and I guess internally the framework throws exception.
3. Trying to parse the data to `object[]` does not require parsing null to integer, so now you know why it works in this case

Answer (score 0):

the json format is incorrect based on what i can see from the question. missing "}" and "]" too.

Comment: so what can i do? how can I stringify it in other way?

Comment: this is the entire json: "[{"id":"201669887","name":"אורה","Sunday":"1","Monday":"1","Tuesday":"1","Wednesday":"0","Thursday":"1","Friday":"1","Sunday1":"1","Monday1":"1","Tuesday1":"1","Wednesday1":"0","Thursday1":"1","Friday1":"0","totalWorkHour":9,"th":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"year":" ","schoolName":null,"schoolNumber":null},{......(shortened)........,"totalWorkHour":9,"th":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",,"","","","","","",""],"year":" ","schoolName":null,"schoolNumber":null}]"